# division of two integrations

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am new to calculus. Today when I read the exponential family, 
The exponential family are defined as below:

$$ p(x|\alpha) = h(x)exp\{  \alpha T(x) - A(\alpha)\}$$

$ T(x) $ is referred to as sufficient statistics. and $A(\alpha)$ satisfied the formular in the bottom.

there is one formular which I did not understand which is:

$$  \int T(x)exp\{ \alpha T(x) \}h(x)dx  \over \int exp\{ \alpha T(x) \}h(x)dx $$
$$ = \int T(x)exp\{ \alpha T(x) - A(\alpha) \}h(x)dx $$

where $ A(\alpha) = log \int h(x)exp\{ \alpha T(x)  \}dx $

I am quite confused why how does this come out?
Is there any theorem for the division of two integrations?

Comment: No, in general there's no nice way to deal with the division of integrals. It looks like you have some special case here; what is the context? What are $T(x)$ and h(x)?

Comment: Hello. I updated my questions. This is just the standard exponential family distribution.